# Topology of $x^2+y^2 = 1$ over $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, analytic-geometry

I am trying to prove that 
$$V=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2| \ x^2+y^2 = 1\} \simeq \mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$$
where $\simeq$ is to be intended as homeomorphic.

Fix  $y\neq \pm 1$ then $x^2 = 1-y^2$ gives me *two* distinct solutions for $x$. It follows that $V$ will contain two disjoint copies of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\pm 1\}$.

Now  it remains to see if there is any solution of the form  $(x,\pm 1)$. 
There are exactly two solutions $\{(0, \pm 1)\}$.
Then it seems reasonable to me that $V$ is obtained filling the two points in the two  copies of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\pm 1\}$ and identifying the points $\pm 1$, more explicitely
$$V = \frac{(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\pm 1\} )\times \{a,b\}}{\sim}$$
where $(+1,a)\sim (+1,b)$ and $(-1,a) \sim (-1,b).$

The problems is that this is not the cylinder $\mathbb{C}^*$, indeed if we remove the two points $[(\pm 1,a)]$ we disconnect $V$ while $\mathbb{C}^*$ remains connected.

> what is wrong?

Comment: Leaving this as a comment instead of an answer since it answers the original question but doesn't explain why your approach is wrong. Note that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ iff $(x+iy)(x-iy) = 1$. So the map $(x, y) \mapsto (x+iy, x-iy)$ identifies your set with the subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ consisting of pairs whose product is one; this is then homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^\times$ since the second coordinate is determined by the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach shows the following:

We have a map $V \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto y$. This map is surjective. The fiber over every point other than $y= \pm 1$ has size two, and the fiber over the two points $y = \pm1$ has size one.

You have concluded that away from $\pm 1$ this is the trivial (disconnected) double cover, and the rest is obtained by a gluing process. But even before we get to the gluing part, the part about the trivial double cover is already not true; for example, take $y = 0$. Then we can connect the two pre-images of $y$ in $V$ by an arc in $V$ (just take a path from $x=1$ to $x=-1$ in $\mathbb{C}$ which avoids $x=0$).

For a different approach, see the comment I left on the question.

Comment: Thanks this will remember me the possible issues that arise reasoning in the above way.